# Delete parent and the clicked button container with inline jquery code

Tags: jquery

I have this code that adds some form and button

```
addAdditionalBedroom: function (n) {
      //this.bedrooms_number_container = this.bedrooms_number_container + 1;
      $("."+n).append("<div class='row blueDiv' id='"+n+"'><div class='col-md-4'> <label>Types Of Beds</label> <select class='form-control'><option>One</option><option>Two</option><option>Three</option><option>Four</option> </select> <br /></div><div class='col-md-4'> <label>Number Of Beds</label> <input type='number' class='form-control' placeholder='Number Of Beds'/></div><div class='col-md-4'> <br /><button id='"+n+"' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='$("+'#'+n+").remove()'>Delete</button></div></div>");
    },
```

The function above is called when a button is clicked so the form and the button have identical ids(i know i should be using classes for that)

I want when the button delete is clicked, it executes some inline jquery code and remove the entire div `blueDiv` and also the clicked button.

My inline jquery code looks like this

```
<button id='"+n+"' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='$("+'#'+n+").remove()'>Delete</button>
```

the problem is, the onclick code forms without quotes and also, doesnt remove the entire parent. How can i fix this?

The accepted answer is the correct way of doing it, although if anyone wants to keep the inline code this is what solved it for me

```
addAdditionalBedroom: function (n) {
  //this.bedrooms_number_container = this.bedrooms_number_container + 1;
  $("."+n).append("<div class='row blueDiv' id='"+n+"'><div class='col-md-4'> <label>Types Of Beds</label> <select class='form-control'><option>One</option><option>Two</option><option>Three</option><option>Four</option> </select> <br /></div><div class='col-md-4'> <label>Number Of Beds</label> <input type='number' class='form-control' placeholder='Number Of Beds'/></div><div class='col-md-4'> <br /><button id='"+n+"' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='$(this).closest(`.row`).remove()'>Delete</button></div></div>");
},
```

Comment: Why not `$(this).remove()` ? Also I don't know that jQuery will work inline like that. Why not just bind the click callback in the script header?

Comment: @Twisty that was my first guesss but only removes the button you clicked. Closest row complains of unexpected character `$(this).closest('.row').remove()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use inline JS code, incremental ids or shared ids. All are anti-patterns which cause more issues than they solve.

To achieve your goal remove the duplicated incremental `id` attributes and instead use DOM traversal to add the content based on the location of the 'add' button which was clicked.

In addition, remove the inline click handler and use a single delegated event handler for all 'delete' buttons, again using the DOM traversal `closest()` method to find the nearest parent `.row` element and remove it from the DOM. Try this:

```js
let foo = {
  addAdditionalBedroom: function($container) {
    $container.append('<div class="row blueDiv"><div class="col-md-4"><label>Types Of Beds</label><select class="form-control"><option>One</option><option>Two</option><option>Three</option><option>Four</option> </select><br /></div><div class="col-md-4"><label>Number Of Beds</label><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Number Of Beds"/></div><div class="col-md-4"><br /><button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" type="button">Delete</button></div></div>');
  }
}

// add
$('.add').on('click', e => {
  let $house = $(e.target).closest('.house');
  foo.addAdditionalBedroom($house);
});

// remove
$(document).on('click', '.btn-delete', e => {
  $(e.target).closest('.row').remove();
});
```

```css
.house {
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="house">
  <button type="button" class="add">Add bedroom</button>
</div>
<div class="house">
  <button type="button" class="add">Add bedroom</button>
</div>
<div class="house">
  <button type="button" class="add">Add bedroom</button>
</div>
```

In addition, including that much HTML in your JS logic is also against best practices. I'd suggest using a template library or even just cloning hidden content in your HTML page and appending from there. That's a little off-topic for this question, though.

Comment: This is too much modification and i am calling the code inside a method. If this would work inline $(this).closest('.row').remove() that would have the best outcome for me.

Comment: Granted, there's a fair bit of modification here, but that's because I'm trying to show you the best way to approach your issue. Using inline code, or relying on incremental ids will lead to overly complicated code which is terrible to maintain and extend.

Comment: Fair enough. your way is the correct way of doing it, although my inline method is for a single use case in an otherwise vue js app with very many nested objects and have reched at the edge of reactivity and i cant benefit from reactivity anymore in my case so some good ol jquery to the resque.